# Node.js: javascript ООП, зачем такие конструкции?

Tags: javascript, ооп, node.js

Начал изучать Node.js и часто вижу такие конструкции:

```
var Network = function(url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

Зачем присваивают текущим свойствам их же внутри?

Answer (score 9):

Вероятно Network - это функция-конструктор (в общем понимании - класс). Позже из этой функции будет создаваться экземпляр класса. Что бы url был доступен всем методам нового объекта, переменную url необходимо записать в свойство объекта.
Попробуйте выполнить следующий код и поймете в чем дело.

```
Network = function(url) { this.url = url; }
Network.prototype = {
    testProperties: function() {
      console.log(typeof url); // undefined;
      console.log(this.url); // ru.stackoverflow.com
    }
};
var stackoverflow = new Network('ru.stackoverflow.com');
stackoverflow.testProperties();
```

Answer (score 3):

в конструкции

```
var Network = function(url) { this.url = url; }
```

Network - это класс. При создании экземпляра этого класса (`new Network('http://...')`) функции-конструктору передается параметр `url`.
И этот экземпляр класса (this) сохраняет данный `url` в своих свойствах объекта `this->url`для использования в будущем.